# connection string adds database to sql instead of reading from a database

Tags: c#, sql, web-config

I have been trying to learn how to use sql express with C# and I am having difficulty connecting to a database that already has data in it.  When I connect to the sql server my program adds a new database instead of reading the one that is currently in the sql server.

Here is my connection string which I think is where the issue is.

```
<add name="GolfLeague1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
     connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebUI-20140205175325;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebUI-20140205175325.mdf" />
```

This gives me a new database called GolfLeague1(WebUI). Which I can read and write to, but it is not what I would like to do.

I have tried the string with and without a "Database=".

What part of the big picture am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have specified 'AttachDbFileName' property when you already have specified the database name. This part is not required here.
You can use the below mentioned connection string.

```
<add name="GolfLeague1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" 
 connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebUI-20140205175325;Integrated Security=SSPI;" />
```

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I did some more research on the options and was able to make the connection string work, but not as a localdb with a MDF file.  Not sure if that is a bad thing or not. Here is the string that I used.                                  <add name="GolfLeague1" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" connectionString="Data Source=mike-hp\sqlexpress;Initial Catalog=GolfLeague1;Integrated Security=True;"  />

Comment: My pleasure. Did I miss anything to mention?

Comment: Because you are using windows authentication, so you need to set integrated security =true.

Comment: I don't think you missed anything I just can't seem to get the proper connection using a local data source (Data Source=(localdb)v11.0). It always seem to make it's own DB in sql express.  I was reading that it is safer to use a MDF file as an intermediary between the sql database.